# how to jump through form elements? webdriver

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to jump through form elements, the same way you do when you hit tab. I can't find a webdriver way to do this yet. This is for when I know the order of the form and don't need to worry about ids or names to find the element. Thank you

Comment: Have you tried `sendKeys(Keys.TAB)`?

Comment: `sendKeys()` method this is `Java` not `Python`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate through list of input fields using `Keys.TAB`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
list = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('input')
for input_field in list:
    input_field.send_keys("enter some text here")
    input_field.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
```

Comment: that simple huh. I did `xdotool key Tab` first, but it tabs the actual terminal it ran in, which makes sense. let me test